# Unlimited Div width? Is it possible?

Tags: css

In my project, I need to implement a container div that should have an unknown (unlimited) width, without breaking to a new line if its width overflows through the browser's window.

The container div has the CSS property of (white-space: nowrap; display:inline;) and the components inside this div has (float:left) CSS property. All widths are set statically. To test the behaviour, i used a button that calls a javascript function that appends a component inside the container div.

The problem is that when the total width of the container div increased to more than the browser's window width, the components inside the container div will break to a new line. I wonder whether it is possible to have a div with unlimited width?

Many Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `white-space: nowrap` property *does not apply to floated elements*. Simply put, when you float an element to the left or right, *there is no white space between them*.

See [white-space (CSS property)](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/white-space) for more information on what white space is and the line that specifically states you can't do this with floats.

Try setting them to `display: inline-block` so that the parent actually considers them to be content.

Comment: I see.. now I realize that white-space property works only for texts (am i right?) ... So, do you have any suggestions for my problem? how to avoid line break, even if the container div's width overflows through the browser's window? thanks..

Comment: @Abou: See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/sT2DV/) about using `display: inline-block` instead. All you have to worry about is making sure there aren't line breaks and spaces between each element so that excess space does not appear between them.

Comment: Here is [another example](http://jsfiddle.net/sT2DV/1/) without line breaks and spaces.

Comment: Nice shot! thanks for the answer.. i got wrong about the whitespace too.. your simple example really clear things out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a specific height to the container div, or removing the `float: left` rule from the components inside the div.

Comment: I have specifically set the height of the divs, still won't work. and the float: left, I think it should be set that way, if not, the divs inside the container won't flow in one line.. IMHO..